# FB Login not working when using jquery in the same page

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have developed my application using codeigniter framework and jquery, but now I need to integrate facebook login and the ads api into it, so I tried to use the facebook js sdk. It worked perfectly when using it outside my codeigniter as a subfolder, but when integrating it within the app it is not working.

I am using this code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
   appId      : '<?php echo FB_APP_ID;?>',
   xfbml      : true,
   version    : 'v2.5'
 });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function myFacebookLogin() {
     FB.login(function(response){
         console.log("Hello",response);
           if(response.authResponse)
           {
                FB.api('me/accounts',function(response){
                 console.log("Successfully retrieved pages",response);  
                });
           }
          }, {scope: 'manage_pages,ads_management'});
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFacebookLogin()" style="cursor: pointer;padding: 15px; text-align: center; background:#303030; color:#FFF; font-weight: bold; width: 150px;">FB Login </button>
```

After this I am using jquery for other purposes in my app, like drag-drop, move, carousel etc.

But when I try to integrate the same code within my app which has a lot of jquery in it, it throws an error in the console as

Error: Not valid UTF-8

I am using jquery 1.8.3 but tried to use the latest versions too without any luck.

Can any one help me with this please.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No valid information such as linenumbers?
Try firebug in firefox as a debugger.

Comment: hi Leif thanks for your quick reply... the error is shown in the facebook js file on line 58

Comment: hi Leif sorry I missed the screenshot of console.... the error is shown in the facebook js file on line 58
    Error: Not valid UTF-8

...RIComponent(escape(m));}catch(o){throw new Error('Not valid UTF-8');}},encodeObj...

http://prntscr.com/ard5k3 shows the console log error.

Comment: This is in a function Base64, but the file is obfuscated, and you need to see the trace to find what its parameters are.

Comment: Its facebook js so cannot change or debug it. I only have access to the code snippet I used in question.

Comment: You could download the facebook js, and run it from your own server.

Comment: Ok thanks I will give that a try.

Comment: @Leif Neland 
 
When debug and console logged the function it outputted this code...
`code` check the element {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":"AQAoKGpXofNQzOrDf2Nz96IqFu0d_Uw_y4WMNKiuNg7YIR1vidJa7zBG0BG4b7owTJMyexkwYsJEUoIQ0zT8Ul-064SOtOy6at9dtfaHbA1EHgtbE4Ke-gQ0poQOb-nAtlSx6nqT31B3ACRSRQJQDC-uZc92Oalu9Pj_u-lPvtLbDdXLTWRpIxTTLGh-uNI-gqa-1ZgoGCyYVW2PMcv_sR7u1wiXvaPiIjVi4dTdXKPV1yuO9ZHKPCH0RSsq8GPRDj-kaoCip6LHPlTum3HxQl6scnk4B9ORCxQ5r7jq-BJ89fNj5e_qMD3wUAduApYIgnPn8Fo3tuZ6ZIvFuH9VELAt","issued_at":1460476181,"user_id":"1783272561903976"}

Comment: On that, I'll throw in the towel. :-(

Comment: Hi Leif Nelend... the is resolved.. after debugging a lot I found that the issue is with javascript code. I had declared a variable called  "escape", which is a predefined identifier in javascript. renaming it resolved the issue. But the error displayed in the console.log was confusing.

Comment: Glad you got it solved.